# PG db:structure:load results in sh error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm executing the following command

`bundle exec rake db:structure:load`

And getting this error:

`sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I realized this was due to having a parenthesis in the path in which the command was being executed